# How to code this table

Tags: tables

I tried to produce this table but I have problem with my code.
How can I change my code to obtain the desired output?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{ |c| }{x=0.5&x=0.6 & x=0.7} \\
 \hline
 MD &RM& MD\\ \hline
 3& 8 & 7 \\
 4 & 10& 8\\
 5& 3& 9 \\
 \\ \hline

 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Garry, you could consider going through your questions and [accept the best answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to each (if it has solved your problem of course), this will mark the question as solved, and award some points to the both answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 7):

You're misusing `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |*{6}{c|} }
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{$x=0.5$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{$x=0.6$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{$x=0.7$} \\
\hline
MD & RM& MD & RM & MD & RM \\
\hline
3 &  8 & 7 & 11 & 0 & 1 \\
4 & 10 & 8 & 12 & 4 & 2 \\
5 &  3 & 9 &  1 & 3 & 0 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{$y=70$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{$z=50$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{$xy=10$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `multirow` is not needed (it is almost never).

A different realization using `booktabs`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$x=0.5$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$x=0.6$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$x=0.7$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
MD & RM& MD & RM & MD & RM \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
3& 8 & 7 & 11 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 10& 8 & 12 & 4 & 2\\
5& 3& 9 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$y=70$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$z=50$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$xy=10$} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A further refinement with `siunitx` that allows better placement of numbers:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ *{6}{S[table-format=2.0]} } % two digits for the integral part, no decimals
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$x=0.5$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$x=0.6$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$x=0.7$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
{MD} & {RM} & {MD} & {RM} & {MD} & {RM} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
3& 8 & 7 & 11 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 10& 8 & 12 & 4 & 2\\
5& 3& 9 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$y=70$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$z=50$} &
\multicolumn{2}{ c }{$xy=10$} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Garry I added two different versions; avoid vertical rules.